# Excel - Checking if cells in range match and then replace cell

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula

I need to check if cell `A5`(Song Name), `B5`(Album), `C5`(Artist) is the same text as any text in Worksheet 2 from `A5:A104`, `B5:B104`, `C5:C105`, respectively.

And if it does, I want the cell I am writing this formula in to change to the same value at `E5:E104` from Worksheet 2.

This is what I made, which does not work:

```
=IF(AND(A5='Worksheet 2'!A5:A104,B5='Worksheet 2'!B5:B104,C5='Worksheet 2'!C5:C104),'Worksheet 2'!E5,"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the values in E5:E104 numbers or text?

Comment: All the cells contain text, including E5:E104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array formula to do this.  What you were trying to do was nearly right, but it won't work as you expect unless you enter it as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Try this, entered as an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Worksheet 2'!$E$1:$E$104,MIN(IF(A5='Worksheet 2'!$A$5:$A$104,IF(B5='Worksheet 2'!$B$5:$B$104,IF(C5='Worksheet 2'!$C$5:$C$104,ROW('Worksheet 2'!$E$5:$E$104),2000000),2000000),2000000))),"No match found.")
```

The logic gets complicated by the fact that you have to use a function that can return a single value from an array (`MIN()` in this formula).

Comment: Note that `IFERROR()` is only available in Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. I didn't know to omuch about array formulas, you've opened a new door for me!

Comment: By the way is there a method to check multiple worksheets? Say I had 5 worksheets and I wanted to check all of them and if one worksheet has it, then it will use the data, otherwise it will move onto the next worksheet and check that one.

Comment: yes - instead of `"No Match Found"`, copy and paste the formula in again, changing the `Worksheet_2` references. It's going to be a pain to debug though  
Or, place the formula's in a separate section, without the `IFERROR` and then test each cell in the one you want to display, nesting the `IFERROR` test

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A5&B5&C5,'Worksheet 2'!A5:A104&'Worksheet 2'!B5:B104&'Worksheet 2'!C5:C104,0)),"",'Worksheet 2'!E5)`
Enter as an array function with Ctrl+Shift+Enter